# ElasticSearch Nest, edge n gram with Fuziness

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using ElastiSearch.Net and NEST v7.10.0
I have these settings and mappings for elastic search.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {},
                "analyzer": {
                    "keyword_analyzer": {
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "asciifolding",
                            "trim"
                        ],
                        "char_filter": [],
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "keyword"
                    },
                    "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase"
                        ],
                        "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
                    },
                    "edge_ngram_search_analyzer": {
                        "tokenizer": "lowercase"
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer": {
                    "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
                        "type": "edge_ngram",
                        "min_gram": 2,
                        "max_gram": 50,
                        "token_chars": [
                            "letter"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "MatchName": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keywordstring": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
                    },
                    "edgengram": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
                        "search_analyzer": "edge_ngram_search_analyzer"
                    },
                    "completion": {
                        "type": "completion"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "CompetitionName": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keywordstring": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
                    },
                    "edgengram": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
                        "search_analyzer": "edge_ngram_search_analyzer"
                    },
                    "completion": {
                        "type": "completion"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": "standard"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have indexed 3 documents with values

```
{
    "_source": {
        "CompetitionName": "Premiership",
        "MatchName": "Dundee Utd - St Johnstone",
    }
},
{
    "_source": {
        "CompetitionName": "2nd Div, Vastra Gotaland UOF",
        "MatchName": "IF Limhamn Bunkeflo - FC Rosengaard 1917",
    }
},
{
    "_source": {
        "CompetitionName": "Bundesliga",
        "MatchName": "Hertha Berlin - Eintracht Frankfurt",
    }
}
```

And i am searching with Fuziness.Auto in both fields with string "bunde".
I want to achieve to get all the documents with the search above.
But for the query below i get nothing.

```
string value = "bunde";
BoolQuery boolQuery = new BoolQuery
{
    Should = new List<QueryContainer>
    {
        new QueryContainer(new FuzzyQuery
        {
            Field = Infer.Field<EventHistoryDoc>(path:eventHistoryDoc => eventHistoryDoc.MatchName),
            Value = value,
            Fuzziness = Fuzziness.Auto,
        }),
        new QueryContainer(new FuzzyQuery
        {
            Field = Infer.Field<EventHistoryDoc>(path:eventHistoryDoc => eventHistoryDoc.CompetitionName),
            Value = value,
            Fuzziness = Fuzziness = Fuzziness.Auto,
        })
    }
};

ISearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest
{
    Query = new QueryContainer(boolQuery),
};

var json = _elasticClient.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(searchRequest);

ISearchResponse<EventHistoryDoc> searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<EventHistoryDoc>(searchRequest);
```

If i search with string "bundes" i get only one document

```
{
    "_source": {
        "CompetitionName": "Bundesliga",
        "MatchName": "Hertha Berlin - Eintracht Frankfurt",
    }
}
```

Any idea about changes should i do to settings, mapping or query in order to get as response all the documents above?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the syntax of Elasticsearch Nest, but in JSON format you can achieve your result in the following way:

Adding a working example with index mapping, search query, and search result
(For now, I have removed the `keyword_analyzer` and `edge_ngram_search_analyzer` from the index mapping, as you just wanted to return all the documents with edge ngram along with fuzziness)

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "my_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 50,
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "max_ngram_diff": 50
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "CompetitionName": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            },
            "MatchName": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "bunde",
      "fuzziness": "AUTO"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64968421",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.483365,
        "_source": {
          "CompetitionName": "Premiership",
          "MatchName": "Dundee Utd - St Johnstone"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "64968421",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 2.4444416,
        "_source": {
          "CompetitionName": "Bundesliga",
          "MatchName": "Hertha Berlin - Eintracht Frankfurt"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "64968421",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.6104546,
        "_source": {
          "CompetitionName": "2nd Div, Vastra Gotaland UOF",
          "MatchName": "IF Limhamn Bunkeflo - FC Rosengaard 1917"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**The index mapping provided in the question is also correct. When using the same index mapping (as provided in the question) and searching for `bunde` in the multi-match query (as shown above), all the three documents are returned (which is the expected result).**

Comment: What version of elasticsearch do you use?
I have exact the same results as before with your changes.
When i search "bunde" i get no results and when i search "bundes" i get 1 document with JSON format as you.

Comment: @CHARISMEGALOS I am using Elasticsearch version 7.8. I tried it locally also when I am searching for `bunde` OR `bundes`, I am getting all the three documents (which is your expected result)

Comment: I updated elastisearch to 7.10.0 and i am ok with both approaches. Many thanks for the answer. I had 7.9.x

Comment: @CHARISMEGALOS glad this worked for you  Can you please accept and upvote my answer as well if it helped you resolve your issue 